# What happens when some functions take a long time? Are they asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have code like:

```
app.get('/url', (req, res) => {
  if (req.some_magic == 1) {
    do_1();
  }
});

function do_1() {
  let requests = get_requests();
  setTimeout(function() { request({
    "uri": "url",
    "method": "POST",
    "json": rq
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    do_1();
  })}, 1000})
}
```

Basically for some requests that come to `/url`, I have to send bunch of requests to some service. How can I make this asynchronous so other requests from other people coming to `/url` wouldn't have to wait for `do_1` to be finished? Or Node is already working like that? If yes, do you have any quick explanations or tutorials I could look into to understand how this works? I come from LEMP, so it's super different. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204).  This is essentially how almost all http APIs are built (using promises). The above http calls will be called asynchronously. You should *not* use `setTimeout` to check the result of any call. Use the native promise object instead. See the answer on the link for how to do that.

Comment: `Or Node is already working like that?` Node already works like that. between the time `request(...)` and `(err, res, body) => {
    do_1();
  }` are invoked, the process is free to handle new incoming requests and run more asynchronous functions that process I/O in the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any function that involves getting data from outside of Node (such as a network request or file read) will use a function that is asynchronous. The documentation for the function should tell you (or at least imply it saying that the function returns a Promise or accepts a callback function as an argument).

The example you give shows the `request` module accepting a callback function.

The main exceptions are functions which are explicitly defined as being sync (such as [fileWriteSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)).

If you need to free up the main event loop explicitly, then you can use a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). It's very rare that you will need to do this, and the main need comes when you are performing CPU intensive calculations in JS (which aren't farmed out to a library that is already asynchronous).